# how to change theme mode & theme color based on both system dark mode or onclick event in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

- Color ThemeMode is based on 2 different ways,
  The first is that the color theme is change based on the system theme. (if the user selects the dark mode from the device then my app color theme is also changed with dark mode.)
  The second is that the color theme is based on the onClick Event from the application.

I want to create these two tasks with a single variable, like, if the system mode is on light mode but the user changes the mode of application in dark mode...and also if the system is on dark mode then the application is automatically converted into dark mode.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for that on pub.dev called [theme_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/theme_provider). Have you tried it? You can add it to your pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: But in this package if i select dark mode from my device (Means dark mode from mobile default features) then the application is not set in dark theme mode.

Let me explain :
I want to create theme mode like whatsapp.  we can set dark theme with the whatsapp feature and also if we set dark theme then whatsapp automatically convert into dark theme.

Comment: Do you want to set light mode in your app when dark mode is enabled in your mobile settings? Or just want to override your app's settings when the mobile theme settings are changed?

Comment: Yes, exactly..!